# C++ splitting a string based on a certain character but occurring only at certain places

Tags: c++, string, substring

I am receiving a single string from a web application that I wish to break down into individual sub string for some sort of token based processing.The string I receive is dynamic in the sense there is no fixed number of sub strings each time and each sub string has a slightly different structure.

Here is an example below:

> {"name":"Move","user":1,"robot":2,"map":1,"x":"4","y":"87"},{"name":"Wait","user":1,"robot":2,"map":1,"mins":"3"},{"name":"ReturnHome","user":1,"robot":2,"map":1,"RH":"yes"}

Now say I want to split this based on the "," after each "}", so that I can get 3 individual sub strings and store them in a vector. I am not very well versed with C++, but the methods I have found and tried so far breaks into sub strings at every occurrence of a ",".

The below is the code I am using to get the string to this stage from the direct one I am receiving

```
       std::stringstream ss(msg->data.c_str());
        std::stringstream ss_1;
        while (ss.good()) 
        {
            std::string substr;
            getline(ss, substr, '[');
            v.push_back(substr);
        }
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout <<"\n This is after first iteration:"<< v[i] << std::endl;
            ss_1.str(v[i]);
        }
        while (ss_1.good()) 
        {
            std::string substr;
            getline(ss_1, substr, ']');
            u.push_back(substr);
        }
```

Worst case scenario, I can proceed with an extension of this, but it leaves me with a lot of edge cases to handle, so I was wondering if there was an elegant way to implement this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using a JSON parsing library?

Comment: Your question is almost exactly the example of a XY problem, with the answer: use a json parser https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: split it at `}`. Its unclear why there is `]` in your code. There is no `]` in the string

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I haven't explored JSON parser, but yes, it seems to be a better use case rather than strings. Will explore the same, thank you! It did not occur to me earlier as I am using this inside ROS, therefore I just decided to proceed with a string

Comment: @gerum ha ha, yeah my bad, will explore the JSON parser instead of strings.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number those were needed for pre processing to get to the string I have mentioned

Comment: This one is often used : https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/

Comment: Thanks @PepijnKramer, it's just that I am not sure how to integrate it with ROS

Comment: If one of you can post the JSON comment as answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it and kinda close this